# Quadratic Equation Solver Math Domain Error

Tags: python

I am trying to make a quadratic equation solver, but each time I run it, it displays a math domain error. Can anyone help me fix it? I am sorta new to Python.

```
import math
def quadratic(a, b, c):
    return [((-b + i * math.sqrt(b**2 - 4*a*c)) / (2 * a)) for i in (-1,1)]

a = int(input("What is the value of a? "))
b = int(input("What is the value of b? "))
c = int(input("What is the value of c? "))
print(quadratic(a, b, c))
```

Comment: Don't post unindented Python code. The indentation affects the meaning of the code.

Comment: Have you tried different input values? This error can mean that a `sqrt` gets a negative input value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works in general, but should check if `b**4-a*c` is positive. That is (probably) why you are getting an error

```
def quadratic(a, b, c):
    D = b**2 - 4*a*c
    if D >= 0:
        return [((-b + i * math.sqrt(D)) / (2 * a)) for i in (-1, 1)]
    else:
        return None
```

Comment: I think you meant `D=b**2 - 4*a*c`, then `return [((-b + i * math.sqrt(D)) / (2 * a)) for i in (-1, 1)]`